# Loads style and/or animation before show the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some advice about my problem.

I'm using a JQ Multiselect and JQ Uniform to make more of the pages hotties.

The problem is.... The JQ are applied after the page has already loaded and it happens that you see the page without the "effects" (for about 1 second) and then start the effects / styles. 
And this thing is horrible and frustrating.

Before writing here I took a tour on StackOverflow and on the internet but I can not find the solution to my problem.

Note: obviously, in the head tag I have the src of single js and othe  tags before and after my "Javascript problem".

I tried with

```
<head>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).load(function(){
    $('#SomeID').multiselect({});
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
```

and with

```
<head>
 <script>

   $(window).load(function(){
    $('#SomeID').multiselect({});
   });

 </script>
</head>
```

but is the same thing!!!

You think there's a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do CSS `display: none` on the body or all the main sections of your page, so that when the entire page is loaded all the contents of it are hidden. You can then use whatever JavaScript effects you want to change the display property.

Comment: Yes!!! Ok, You have given me an input, not the complete solution. But I solves my problem, searching for to add and remove a div css after x seconds.